# Why does text-area alter the baseline of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I know that elements with `display: inline-block` with `display: value-other-than-visible` (can) make the baseline of their parent position at the bottom of the inline-block's hpbm (height, padding, border, margin).

Why does `text-area` seem to produce the same effect? I know most user-agents make it `inline-block`.

For example:

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
I am text.
<span>I am a span.</span>
<textarea></textarea>
```

---

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
I am text.
<span>I am a span.</span>
<div>I am an inline-block</div>
```

Comment: _The HTML specification doesn't define where the baseline of a <textarea> is, so different browsers set it to different positions._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Baseline_inconsistency

Comment: Please set----textarea {vertical-align:top;}-- The <textarea> baseline is set on the baseline of the first line of the textarea, on another browser it may be set on the bottom of the <textarea> box.

Comment: Is the line-height of the `textarea` really the only thing that's responsible for changing the position of the line-height of the parent element?

Comment: line-heights don't have a position.

Comment: @Alohci Sorry meant to say: is the the baseline of the textarea really the only thing that's responsible for changing the position of the baseline of the parent element?

Comment: The short answer is no. Its vertical-alignment will affect it too. But its kind of complicated. because they doesn't affect the baseline of the parent element directly. They affect the baseline of the line-box in which the textarea appears. The line box's baseline may or may not affect the baseline of the parent element.